# How to implement a fill method in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm rather new to prolog and I am trying to implement a method called fill
which has the structure

```
fill(4,1,X).
X = [1,1,1,1]
```

However I not sure how to implement this because I know prolog do not allow indexed list. So how am I suppose to return an array.

Answer (score 4):

```
fill(N, E, Xs) :-
   length(Xs, N),       % Xs is a list of length N
   maplist(=(E), Xs).   % all elements in Xs are equal to E
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay and the simple code. But does this mean prolog does allow arrays.

Comment: No arrays involved! Just lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
%fill(+N,+X,-L) element X is replicated N times
fill(0,_,[]).
fill(N,X,[X|Xs]) :- N > 0, N1 is N-1, fill(N1,X,Xs).
```

Answer (score 0):

[findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 it's the swissknife for list building:

```
fill(N, E, Xs) :- findall(E, between(1, N, _), Xs).
```

Comment: @repeat: maybe there are other languages that take a different approach than Prolog to logic programming. I do like Prolog as a practical programming language, so I attempt to suggest the simplest route that works, let's say, in Clocksin-Mellish old style...